# How to stop mutating state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the first time I've encountered mutability. I have state items - an object with keys that go as id, through allIds I find all id items that need to change the date, but they change all items at once, apparently this is due to mutability and I don’t know how to fix it ... I will really appreciate the help!

```
const allIds = getSubTasksId(Object.values(state.items), payload.id);
allIds.forEach((id) => (state.items[id].date.current = payload.date));
return {
  ...state,
  items: { ...state.items },
};
```

Comment: can you explain your problem little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Your `state.items[id].date.current = payload.date` statement is responsible for mutation.
One of the possible solution.

```
const updatedItems = {};
allIds.forEach((id)=> updatedItems[id] = payload.date);
return {
    ...state,
    items: updatedItems
  }
```

Comment: but updatedItems doesn't store anything, does it?

Comment: `updatedItems[id] = payload.date` is responsible for adding the date object.